# Optimize code of a function for a search filter in django with variable numbers of keywords - too much code, i'm a beginner

Tags: django, filter, keyword

Hello great community,

i'm learning django/python development, i'm training myself with development of a web app for asset inventory.

i've made a search filter, to give result of (for example) assets belonging to a specific user, or belonging to a specific department, or belonging to a specific brand, model or category (computers, desks, ecc..) there are many fields that mostly are foreign tables, main table is "Cespiti" that mean Asset in italian

now (after a lot) i've done with multiple keyword search (for example)  somebody type in the search box the department and the category and obtain the relative results (for example all desks in a specific department, or all computer of a specific model in a specific department).

i've made it in a "if" check form that split the keyword in single words, count it and apply progressive filtering on the results of the previous keys in sequence.

but i'm not satisfact of my code, i think it's too much "hardcoded" and instead of creating an IF condition for each number of keyword (from 1 to 3) i wish like to code something that is not so dependent in the number of keyword, but is free.

Here's the code of the view, i hope someone can give me the right direction.

```py
def SearchResults(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    chiave =query.split()
    lunghezza = int((len(chiave)))   
    
    if lunghezza == 1:
        object_list = Cespiti.objects.filter(
        Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[0])  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[0])     
        ).distinct
    
    
    elif lunghezza == 2:
        object_list = Cespiti.objects.filter(
        Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[0])  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[0])     
        ).filter(Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[1])  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[1])     
        ).distinct
    
    elif lunghezza == 3:
        object_list = Cespiti.objects.filter(
        Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[0])  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[0])     
        ).filter(Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[1])  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[1]) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[1])     
        ).filter(Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[2]) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[2])  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[2]) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[2]) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[2]) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[2]) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[2])).distinct
    
    
    context = {
        'object_list': object_list, 'query' : query,
     
    }

   
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Just loop and chain the filters in the loop (keep calling filter with the Query expressions on the same variable and put the result in the same variable).

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it would be to separate the step of building the `Q` objects from the view method. That way it could be performed in a loop:

```py
def generate_search_query_params(word):
    return (
        Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=word) |
        Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=word)  |
        Q(categoria__nome__icontains=word) |
        Q(marca__nome__icontains=word) |
        Q(modello__nome__icontains=word) |
        Q(reparto__nome__icontains=word) |
        Q(matricola__icontains=word)
    )


def SearchResults(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    queryset = Cespiti.objects.all()

    for word in query.split():
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            generate_search_query_params(word)
        )

    object_list = queryset.distinct()
    context = {
        'object_list': object_list, 'query' : query,
    }

    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i really appreciate your suggestion,

i reach to insert in a loop, now number of keywords is unlimited and it's not hardcode ( thanks a lot), i've thinked about Abdul idea and Damon solution, i wish to avoid the initial ".object.all() so i've arranged in this way: the first "level" is fixed, so i can avoid the .all() and all sublevels of filtering are looped, what do you think about?

```
def SearchResults(request):
query = request.GET.get('q')
chiave =query.split()
lunghezza = int((len(chiave)))

object_list = Cespiti.objects.filter(
    Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
    Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[0])  |
    Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
    Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
    Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
    Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[0]) |
    Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[0])     
    )

for I in range(1,lunghezza):
    
    print(I)
    object_list = object_list.filter(
    Q(proprietario__cognome__icontains=chiave[I]) |
    Q(proprietario__nome__icontains=chiave[I])  |
    Q(categoria__nome__icontains=chiave[I]) |
    Q(marca__nome__icontains=chiave[I]) |
    Q(modello__nome__icontains=chiave[I]) |
    Q(reparto__nome__icontains=chiave[I]) |
    Q(matricola__icontains=chiave[I])     
    )

context = {
    'object_list': object_list, 'query' : query,
 
}


return render(request, 'search_results.html', context=context)
```